# onLoad event triggers only when the actual image is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onload

I'm working on a React project which involves getting height of components. A component contains a logo, and I want to get the width of the whole thing including the **loaded** image. `componentDidMount()` doesn't work in this case because it triggers before the image has been loaded. I used `onLoad` event in the `<img>` tag but React returns the height of the alternative text, not the actual image. I have posted the following code for reference:

```
class ElHeader extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);       
        this.state = {
            dropdownTopPos: 0,
            navPad: 0,
            boxShadow: false,
        }
    }
    updateState = () => {
        let headerHeight = this.refHeader.clientHeight,
                navUlHeight = this.refNavUl.clientHeight;
        this.setState({
            headerHeight: headerHeight,
            dropdownTopPos: (headerHeight + navUlHeight)/2,
            navPad: (headerHeight - navUlHeight)/2,
        });
    };
    setBoxShadow = () => {
        this.setState({
            boxShadow: document.documentElement.scrollTop === 0 ? false : true,
        });
    };
    componentDidMount = () => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateState, false);
        document.addEventListener('scroll', this.setBoxShadow, false);
    };
    componentWillUnmount = () => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateState, false);
        document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.setBoxShadow, false);
    };
    render = () => {
        return (
            <div style={{height: this.state.headerHeight - 1}}>
                <Header innerRef={x =>  this.refHeader = x} boxShadow={this.state.boxShadow}>
                        <Container>
                            <Grid>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col>
                                        <div><h1><a href="/"><Logo onLoad={this.updateState} src={mLogo} alt="CKY-UK Logo" /></a></h1></div>
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col stretchWidth>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Row alignEnd="sm" alignMiddle="sm" stretchHeight>
                                            <ul ref={x => this.refNavUl = x}>
                                                <NavUlDesktop>
                                                    <NavLi><NavItem href='/'>Home</NavItem></NavLi>
                                                    <ElDropdown topPos={this.state.dropdownTopPos} itemContent="About us" listContent={[{key: 1, name: 'Leadership Team', link: '#leadership-team'}, {key: 2, name: 'Star players', link: '#star-players'}]} />
                                                    <NavLi><NavItem href='#apply'>Apply</NavItem></NavLi>
                                                    <NavLi><NavItem href='#news'>News</NavItem></NavLi>
                                                    <NavLi><NavItem href="#login"><FontAwesomeIcon icon="sign-in-alt" fixedWidth /> Login</NavItem></NavLi>
                                                </NavUlDesktop>
                                                <ElNavMobile navPad={this.state.navPad} />
                                            </ul>
                                            </Row>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </Grid>
                        </Container>
                </Header>
            </div>
        )
    };
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: *I used onLoad event in the <img> tag but React returns the height of the alternative text, not the actual image.* <-- That doesn't sound right.

Comment: @ScottMarcus what do you mean? It actually returned the height of the alt text and didn't update the size when the actual image loaded

Comment: The `load` event doesn't trigger until the image is fully downloaded and rendered, so you should be getting the correct dimensions. I've never heard of any technique that returns the size of the `alt` text. You must still be getting the size prior to the load event taking place.

Comment: I'm not sure, I guess that's because the alt text is placed inside the h1 tag? @ScottMarcus

Comment: `alt` text is place in `img` elements, not `h1` elements. But, as I say, your code must still be triggering ***prior*** to the `load` event.

Comment: @ScottMarcus what I meant is the whole img tag is placed inside the h1 tag, and when the image has not loaded, the alt text inherits styles from h1 tag

Comment: `alt` text doesn't inherit anything - It can't be styled. `alt` text is "behind-the-scenes" data for those who can't see the image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178260/discussion-between-webdeg-brian-and-scott-marcus).